# ClickOnce Application user settings locations

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am currently developing a ClickOnce application that converts CSV files for a database update. The program requires the user to have the ability to change the configuration files for a database change, and change an XML file which populates a drop-down list in the app.

Now I understand that the files are kept in the user/appdata folder to ensure there have the correct privileges, but do I have any influence as to what those folders are called, or where they are saved?

By default, the files are saved in `AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\LD7ZEJK0.7AE\NJ42PEPW.1QX\csvt...exe_169e1a4011fbe7ec_0001.0000_none_04507fe9e077ae84`

Can I change that to say `Documents\CSV_Files` or something similar? And if I do, how would I reference the XML file in the configuration file so the program knows where it is?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you shouldn't have to care about the location yourself. Just mark your XML file as data in the ClickOnce manifest and access it using the well-known:

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory
```

Here's an MSDN article describing it: [Accessing Local and Remote Data in ClickOnce Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Magnus, that seems to work OK. But I will need access to the config file to change the connection strings. If I hand the program to somebody else and they use it for their database, I just want an easy way to find the file for editing. It should only need editing the first time.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm thick headed, but I don't see the problem. Read the file from that known location, do what's needed with it, and save it back. Isn't that what you're asking?

Comment: Are they always the same folder names? They are on my comp, but what if they were moved to another machine?

Comment: Clickonce installaitions aren't really meant to be moved between machines.