# ClickOnce creates new folders with each update?

Tags: .net, clickonce

So I'm pretty new to ClickOnce, but I have mine setup to automatically pull updates when they're available. The problem I'm having is that it's installing new versions to new folders. This is problematic because one of the included files is a configuration file. In other words, if you spend an hour setting up the app, the new version loses those changes because it gets installed to a new location with the empty config file.

Is there a way to have updates install to the same folder every time and not blow away the file if it exists?

Comment: This is just how clickonce works, check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927062/clickonce-application-user-settings-locations

Comment: Thank you, this article is what I ended up using

Answer (score 1):

Just don't store your config file in your app folder - why should you? Store it somewhere under %localappdata%\YourAppName for example.